# Render JavaServer Faces xhtml to a String on the server

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, portlet

I'm working with a Liferay portlet that uses PrimeFaces 5 for its UI. The typical request renders some XHTML template and sends the resulting HTML to the client. I'd like to render an XHTML file of my choosing to a string in the context of a commandButton action handler.

To illustrate what I'm after, suppose I have the following commandButton definition:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Export as PDF" ajax="false" action="#{myBean.exportPDF}" />
</h:form>
```

When clicked, it executes the exportPDF method of the backing bean. Within that method, I load the contents of another xhtml file into a string. This part is done and works. Now, I'm guessing that I need to parse the string into a UIComponent hierarchy and then to render that hierarchy using the current FacesContext. This is where I'm currently stuck.

The FacesContext has {get,set}ViewRoot methods. The current view root is what the client sees in their browser. How can I replace this view root with one generated from an arbitrary string?

As the button name implies, the desired action is to send the client a PDF. I get the HttpServletResponse instance, output the right headers, and generate the actual PDF content. I'm using Flying Saucer for PDF generation and I'm basically trying to create the input XHTML from a JSF template. Everything already works except for the template bit. The relevant code is below:

```
public void exportPDF() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ITextRenderer r = new ITextRenderer();
    r.setDocumentFromString(getExportXHTML(ctx));
    r.layout();
    r.createPDF(buf);

    HttpServletResponse sr = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(
            (PortletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse());
    sendPDF(sr, buf);
    ctx.responseComplete();
}

private String getExportXHTML(FacesContext ctx) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(4096);
    PortletRequest pr = (PortletRequest)ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    PortletContext pc = pr.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();
    InputStream is = pc.getResourceAsStream("/views/pdf.xhtml");
    try {
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");
        char[] buf = new char[4096];
        int n;
        while ((n = r.read(buf)) != -1) {
            s.append(buf, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    String template = s.toString();

    return ??? // TODO: How do I render template with ctx?
}
```

**SOLVED**

Found the following links that brought me very close to a working solution:

- https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-create-email-from-jsf-templates
- https://github.com/vvasabi/Programmatic-Facelets-Rendering-Example

The only remaining issue was that I couldn't render anything in the action handler. ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse() returned an instance of ActionResponse rather than MimeResponse that's required for rendering. To get around this, I simply rendered XHTML during the initial page load, but waited for the action handler to be called before converting XHTML to PDF. A bit inefficient if the user doesn't want a PDF, but seems to work fine otherwise.

Comment: Is it publicly accessible and idempotent or not? In other words, wouldn't `new URL("http://.../views/pdf.xhtml").openStream()` be sufficient for the job?

Comment: I don't think so. First, this is done in a portlet context, so I don't have the full control of the output (there will be a lot of other stuff added). Second, the server's request will not have the cookies to identify the correct session. I suppose it would be possible to copy that from the request, but the whole thing would be very messy.

Comment: Ah well .. Portlets .. In theory you should be able to able to call `ViewHandler#renderView()` whereby you pass a custom `FacesContextWrapper` wherein the `createResponseWriter()` returns a `ResponseWriter` which writes to a local `StringWriter` or so. It's only quite some code and as I know barely anything about Portlets, I can't guarantee if that would work.